# Nesting DIV with CSS quandary

Tags: css

I'm tyring to nest three divs and have each.  I want the appearance to look like each parent is 10px larger than it's child and be responsive when the horizontal width changes.  When I do this with two DIVs everything works well.

**CSS**

```
#holder
{
 margin:auto;
 width:90%;
 height:150px;
 background-color:#999;
 padding:10px;
 border: 1px solid;
}
#inside
{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#9F0;
 border: 1px solid;
}
```

**HTML**

When I add the third child, that's when it all goes wrong.  The middle child (the green box) moves partially out of it's parent.

**CSS**

```
#holder
{
 margin:auto;
 width:90%;
 height:150px;
 background-color:#999;
 padding:10px;
 border: 1px solid;
}

#inside
{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#9F0;
 border: 1px solid;
 padding:10px;
}

#header
{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#C00;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="holder">
 <div id="inside">
     <div id="header"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do understand padding and margin and that those will add the "real" width and height of the box, but I can not figure out how to get these boxes inside of each other.  things I have tried are below

1. playing with margins and padding
2. playing with different % on the widths of child boxes.  This works to a point, but depending on the width of the browser window the ratio of the distance between the children changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a cascade-type comment list.

Well... Remove the width from #inside and #header. DIVs are [block-level](http://www.codertools.com/css_help_guide/css_block_elements.aspx) elements.

Add

```
#holder div {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Every DIV under #holder will inherit the `padding-left` css property.
I think (and hope :P) that's what you were looking for.

Comment: If you intend to preserve the `width` css property for block-level descendants of `#holder`, then add `box-sizing: border-box;` to both `#holder` and `#holder div` css rules. [About box-sizing CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Comment: Thanks, that got me halfway there.  Following your directions gets #inside and #header inside of #holder horizontally, but they still drop out of the bottom of #holder.

Thanks again for that!

Comment: ah, but since the verticle distance is not changing, I can just change the height of #inside from 100% to 130px and all is good.  THANK YOU!